# Unidirectional OneToMany relationship induces UniqueConstraint

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I'm implementing unidirectional OneToMany between User to Role entities as explained in https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jpa/one-to-many-unidirectional-mapping-in-jpa/

UserDataImpl.java:

```
@Entity
public class UserDataImpl {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    .
    .
    .

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = RoleDataImpl.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_role_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    //Constructors
    //Getters and setters
    //Hashcode and equals
    //toString
}
```

RoleDataImpl.java:

```
@Entity
public class RoleDataImpl {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private byte permissionsInByte = 0;

    //Constructors
    //Getters and setters
    //Hashcode and equals
    //toString
}
```

My UserRepository and RoleRepository both extends JpaRepository. I'm creating an object of user and attaching a Role object to it before saving.

I get following error on saving user in Spring Data JPA:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.entity.impl.RoleDataImpl; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.entity.impl.RoleDataImpl
    .
    .

Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.wehub.entity.impl.RoleDataImpl
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:765)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:758)
    .
    .
```

When I remove the orphanRemoval and cascades:

```
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = RoleDataImpl.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_role_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

I get DataIntegrityException(first object saves normally). Because the role_id in user_roles table will have unique constraint on it. But I want the user_roles entries to be deleted when a user is deleted. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The message of the exception tells you what's wrong: *detached entity passed to persist: com.entity.impl.RoleDataImpl* which means that your instance of `User` holds a reference to `Role` which in turn is not managed by your `EntityManager`.

It should work like this:

```
Role detachedEntity = ...; // from somewhere else

// obtain a managed entity 
// e.g. by name, use what you have at your disposal preferably the ID
Role managedEntity = roleRepository.findByName(detachedEntity.getName());

// assuming you'd initialize a new User like so:
User newUser = new UserDataImpl();
newUser.addRole(managedEntity);

userRepository.save(newUser);
```